# Remote desktop (windows) log on previous user

Tags: windows

When I RDC into a windows machine and then close the remote desktop connection the remote pc is left on the login user screen.

How can I have the PC switch back to the original user when I log off from RDC?

Comment: Can I ask why? I mean, why don't you want to show the login screen?

Comment: By *close the remote desktop connection* do you mean *logoff* or *disconnect* the session?

Comment: the PC is running a kiosk with a custom application, so I want to return to that user running the application without having to restart. Actually when I RDC using an admin account the user will still logged in. I can see this when I run 'quser' in the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your computer is not on a domain controller and is with Windows 7 operating system. In that case the only way is to disable fast user [switching.](http://www.maxi-pedia.com/disable+fast+user+switching+windows+7)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike server versions of windows standard version has only RDP client installed by default, which has a limit of one concurrent user(local or remote).

So when you remotely signin current user is disconnected and hence the user has to login again to access his desktop. There are workarounds, but if you are on an enterprise network check company policies before trying out.

Try the below link.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/655ed2a6-e9fc-486c-bcbe-02fe3f59c206/multiple-rdp-sessions-for-windows-7

Comment: Hopefully by *current user is signed out* you mean *their session is disconnected*. It's not true that the over taken user is actually signed out.

Comment: Yes I meant session disconnection. I've corrected the same.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly convoluted, but if you have the credentials for the account that you want to leave unlocked on the terminal, logging into it using RDP (mstsc.exe), running this in a commandline will leave the PC unlocked on that Desktop session:

```
%windir%\System32\tscon.exe RDP-Tcp#0 /dest:console
```

You need to be in the correct session, though. This won't work for "switching automatically back to the original user" for the same reason that you can't simply log on to other users accounts with your password.